# cannot borrow self as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable for iterator on field

Tags: rust

im making a simple parser for a project of mine and i came across this error which there doesnt seem to be a solution for:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src\compiler\lexer.rs:31:34
   |
29 |         let mut iter = self.file.chars();
   |                        ----------------- immutable borrow occurs here
30 |
31 |         while let Some(lexeme) = self.get_lexeme(&mut iter) {
   |                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---------^
   |                                  |               |
   |                                  |               immutable borrow later used here
   |                                  mutable borrow occurs here
```

ive seen this error before but typically it is easy to solve by moving stuff around, but in this case theres nothing to move around. The struct is mostly straight forward, looks like this:

```rust
pub enum LexemeKind {
    // just some kinds of lexemes, like number or operator
}

pub struct Lexeme {
    pub content: String,
    pub kind: LexemeKind,
}

pub struct Lexer {
    pub file: String,
    pub lexemes: Vec<Lexeme>,
}

impl Lexer {
    pub fn new(file_path: &String) -> Self {
        // just gets file contents and creates empty Vec
    }

    pub fn process(&mut self) { // called in main.rs after Lexer::new()
        let mut iter = self.file.chars();                      // error occurs here

        while let Some(lexeme) = self.get_lexeme(&mut iter) {  // and here
            self.lexemes.push(lexeme);
        }
    }

    fn get_lexeme(&mut self, iter: &mut Chars) -> Option<Lexeme> {
        if self.file.len() == 0 {
            return None;
        }
        
        let kind = get_kind(iter.peek().unwrap());
        // checks the kind of the first character

        let content: String = match kind {
            // pattern matching, assigns function to get token based on kind
            // iter is also used as a parameter for these functions
        };

        Some(Lexeme {
            content,
            kind,
        })
    }

    // functions to get entire token of characters with similair type
    // such as: pub fn get_string(&mut self, iter: &mut Chars) -> String
    // they also call file.split_off(index) and the result is returned
}

fn get_kind(c: char) -> LexemeKind {
    // gets the lexeme kind by checking for opertor, number, brackets, etc.
}
```

im relatively new to rust, and after looking at some other stack overflow questions they dont seem to fit this scenario. any help appreciated

Comment: Just make `get_lexeme` take `&self`?

Comment: the functions that are called in the match statement have &mut self as parameter

Comment: Is cloning possible for you? I.e. in your `process` method: `let file = self.file.clone(); let mut iter = file.chars();`?

Comment: yes cloning works and runs, but im not sure how big the files will be. Is there a more efficient solution or is this the only possible way?

Comment: Perhaps it is not necessary to mutate the lexer while _getting_ lexems? Maybe you could restructure your logic and do what _drewtato_ suggested.

Comment: the reason it needs to be mutable is because the String containing the contents of the file is deleted in chunks as lexemes are taken from it. its not necessary, but uses less memory since the contents of the file only have to exist until a lexeme takes it. when the content is set `let content = match kind {...}` there are functions called which cut out a portion of the file and return it

Comment: It will not save memory because the memory used by the string will not shrink, it will just be less efficient as you always need to copy the bytes around. And Rust is actually saving you here: the `chars()` iterator will interleave with the characters removal and point to the wrong characters, and even after the string end. Remove that logic from `get_lexeme()`.

Comment: ok it makes sense now i didnt understand how iterators really work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options here:

#### 1. Make the parameters in `get_lexeme` non-overlapping

This means that instead of accepting `&mut self`, you only accept the fields mutably you need to mutate:

```rs
    fn get_lexeme(file: &str, lexemes: &mut Vec<Lexeme>, iter: Chars<'_>) -> Option<Lexeme> {
```

Of course this only works if the `get_lexeme` function doesn't mutate `self.file`, as that would violate the borrowing rules.

#### 2. Accept an index into the filename rather than an iterator

Since a `usize` index doesn't have a lifetime, this works:

```rs
    fn get_lexeme(&mut self, index: usize) -> Option<Lexeme> {
        if self.file.len() == 0 {
            return None;
        }
        
        let kind = get_kind(self.file[index..].chars().next().unwrap());
        // etc.
    }
```

You still need to make sure that you don't access any field mutably and immutably at the same time.